# Cache nested Property when mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map 2 objects, where the source one has a couple of Lazy loaded properties that go to DB any time they are used. I cannot change these objects. I can only change the mapping. Here is what I have so far.

```
        CreateMap<CasePlan, CasePlanView>()
            .ForMember(d => d.ProgramId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.ProgramRevisionId))
            .ForMember(d => d.ClientName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.Client.FullName))
            .ForMember(d => d.ClientId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.ClientId))
            .ForMember(v => v.ClientBirthDate, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.Client.BirthDate))
            .ForMember(d => d.EnrollmentStartDate, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.Enrollment.StartDate))
            .ForMember(d => d.Age, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.Client.BirthDate.ToAgeStringAtDate(s.Date).Replace("old", "")))
            .ForMember(d => d.Program, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.ProgramRevision.Program.Abbreviation))
            .ForMember(d => d.PlacementWorker, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.PlacementWorker.Name))
            .ForMember(d => d.ReferralAgencyName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.ReferralSource.Name))
            .ForMember(d => d.CourtStatus, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PrimaryReferral.Client.LegalStatuses.FirstOrDefault() != null ? s.PrimaryReferral.Client.LegalStatuses.First().Status : null))
            .ForMember(d => d.Approver, o => o.MapFrom(r => r.Approver.DisplayName))
            .ForMember(d => d.ApproverId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ApproverId));
```

Everything gets mapped properly, but is very slow! Anytime I use the PrimarryReferral property a call to DB is made. Is there a way to instruct AutoMapper to cache the value and used it for all of the subsequent usages?

Comment: It might help if you showed us the models you're mapping between, in addition to the mapping code.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
CreateMap<CasePlan, CasePlanView>()
     .ConstructUsing((caseplan, b) => { 
          var client= a.PrimaryReferral.Client; 
          return new CasePlanView(){ 
              ClientName= client.FullName,
              ClientBirthDate= client.BirthDate //and so on
    }
    });
```

This way at least you will not access the database more than once for the properties of `a.PrimaryReferral.Client`.
However you would need to access the database for each object that has properties.

One way to fix this would be to eleminate the need for lazy loading using include at the source of `CasePlan`. I don't know if you are able to do that, but that would be my advice.

Another way, which I would not recommend, would be to Inject a `DatabaseContext`(or repository) to the mapper and by using the PK of the `CasePlan`, you get the `CasePlan` again from the database. (That essentially would not map from `CasePlan` object, but would re-get the object from the db. Therefore it would cause additional problems, if the data from the `CasePlan` object is not the same as in the db).